# disabling context menu and mouse in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, contextmenu, flash, swfobject

This should be pretty straight forward.

this should do the trick

```
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void{});
Mouse.hide();
```

and when I run it in the standalone player it works.

However when I run it in a browser, the right-click menu shows up again. I've tried setting the param `wmode="opaque"`, which removes context menu (independent of the code), but shows the mouse despite the css setting: `cursor: none;`

is there a another listener that calls the context menu that can be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the context menu ( and the right click ), you can use `MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK` and / or `MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU` ( available from Flash Player 11.2 and up ) :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU, function(e:MouseEvent):void {});

Mouse.hide();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, `MouseEvent.CONTEXT_MENU`  did it